# Xcode error: This device is no longer connected

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

While executing the project on an iPhone, I am  getting an error while installing the project through Xcode:

> This device is no longer connected.

Whereas I can see the device summary and a green dot if I open the Xcode organiser. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's noting wrong with the cable connecting your iPhone to your computer? I get that message sometimes when the cable gets disconnected.

Comment: Which version of Mac OS X? Which version of Xcode? What kind of device? Which version of iOS? Are you using a connector cable from Apple or 3rd party?

Comment: Yes, The cable is perfectly fine. I am using Mac OS X mountain lion and the device has iOS 5.1 the xcode version is 4.5.2. The OS is running on a virtual machine with windows 7 as host.

Comment: Try clearing the Xcode cache and restarting it.

Comment: Restarted my Virtual Machine, Works!!!

Answer (score 57):

Try quitting Xcode totally and reopening it.

Comment: Just ran into this with xcode 5.1.1; restart xcode fixed it.

Comment: Just had this in 7.3.1

Comment: I can confirm this one too.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation. I tried

- Clean and build
- Restarted Xcode
- Deleted derived data
- Rebooted system

nothing worked for me

**I switched the usb port(from left to right port), It just worked.**

I know it sounds weird, but it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to restart your iPhone and Mac. By doing this your issue will be resolved. This you can try on any version of Xcode

The error comes only after trying to run the project many items, instead of solving the Provisioning Profile issues.

So, it's better to solve the basic error first, or else it will create another hectic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconnect the device and reconnect it. Sometimes this fixes such kind of problems.

If that does not work, closing and reopening Xcode may help.

Although, since you are mentioning a virtual machine, you might check and see whether there are any conflicts in the attribution of the USB port to one system or another (Windows vs. MacOS).

Comment: Done with the first two, no success! And i see a green dot alongside my device in the xcode organiser. So I am hoping its connected.

Comment: have you tried switching off the device? I suppose that Xcode and Organizer talk to different services on the device (just a guess)...

Comment: Did that now, unfortunately no success again!!

Answer (score 0):

iPhone/iPad USB connectivity is finicky as it is, and you're running OS X in an unsupported way. I'd suspect that this is the problem.

If you're running VMware, this may help: [DEBUGGING ON THE IPHONE & IPAD WITH VMWARE](http://www.otakunozoku.com/debugging-on-the-iphone-ipad-with-vmware/)

Basically it's this: Install iTunes on both your host and client OS, as the Apple Mobile Device USB driver for Windows may help your cause.

However, if you're serious about developing for iOS, using a "real" Mac is definitely the easier way.

**UPDATE:** From your comments, I gather that you need to be able to use Accelerometer input in your app. You could use [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) ([in the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/isimulate/id306908756?mt=8)) to send this data from your device to the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Tried, Not working! This is frustrating, I have a snow leopard and and  iPhone running on iOS 5.1. the Xcode for snow leopard doesn't allow me to build applications for my iPhones OS. So I had no option but to switch to virtualisation. Help!!!\

Comment: @ravijimagna Do you need to debug the app on the device, or do you just want to install and test it there?

Comment: I have written code for various motion sensors, which have to be tested on real device. the simulator does not show anything!

Comment: @ravijimagna Yes, but do you need to be able to debug, or do you just need to run the app on the device to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after installing Xcode 5. The solution I found is to restart your system and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. It was a broken cable.